# How do I replace one test in an XML-defined suite with three others in TestNG?

Tags: selenium, testng

Our team uses TestNG to run some tests in Selenium. We need to be able to run a given test on 3 different browsers (Chrome, Firefox, and [sadly] IE). We have a `browser` parameter on our base test class and really we could just declare three tests, one each for each browser; however, we'd really like to just be able to specify the `browser` value as "**Standard 3**" and have that run the test on each browser automatically.

So, I've built a class that implements `ISuiteListener` and attempts to create the new tests on the fly. However, any way I try to add tests fails. That is, no new tests I try to add will be executed by the suite. It's like nothing I did actually changed anything.

Here's my code:

```
public class Standard3BrowserSuiteListener implements ISuiteListener {
    @Override
    public void onStart(final ISuite suite) {
        final XmlSuite xmlSuite = suite.getXmlSuite();
        final Map<String, String> suiteParameters = xmlSuite.getParameters();
        final List<XmlTest> currentTests = new ArrayList<XmlTest>(xmlSuite.getTests());
        final ArrayList<XmlTest> testsToRun = new ArrayList<XmlTest>(currentTests.size());

        for (final XmlTest test : currentTests) {
            final Browser browser;
            final Map<String, String> testParameters = test.getAllParameters();
            {
                String browserParameter = testParameters.get("browser");
                if (browserParameter == null) {
                    browserParameter = suiteParameters.get("browser");
                }

                browser = Util.Enums.getEnumValueByName(browserParameter, Browser.class);
            }

            if (browser == Browser.STANDARD_3) {
                XmlTest nextTest = cloneTestAndSetNameAndBrowser(xmlSuite, test, testParameters, "Chrome");
                xmlSuite.addTest(nextTest);
                testsToRun.add(nextTest); // alternate I've tried to no avail

                nextTest = cloneTestAndSetNameAndBrowser(xmlSuite, test, testParameters, "Firefox");
                xmlSuite.addTest(nextTest);
                testsToRun.add(nextTest); // alternate I've tried to no avail

                nextTest = cloneTestAndSetNameAndBrowser(xmlSuite, test, testParameters, "IE");
                xmlSuite.addTest(nextTest);
                testsToRun.add(nextTest); // alternate I've tried to no avail
            } else {
                testsToRun.add(test);
            }
        }

        // alternate to xmlSuite.addTest I've tried to no avail
        testsToRun.trimToSize();
        currentTests = xmlSuite.getTests();
        currentTests.clear();
        currentTests.addAll(testsToRun);
    }

    private XmlTest cloneTestAndSetNameAndBrowser(final XmlSuite xmlSuite, final XmlTest test,
            final Map<String, String> testParameters, final String browserName) {
        final XmlTest nextTest = (XmlTest) test.clone();
        final Map<String, String> nextParameters = new TreeMap<String, String>(testParameters);
        nextParameters.put("browser", browserName.toUpperCase());

        nextTest.setName(browserName);

        final List<XmlClass> testClasses = new ArrayList<XmlClass>(test.getClasses());
        nextTest.setClasses(testClasses);

        return nextTest;
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish(final ISuite suite) {}
}
```

How can I replace the test with the `browser` value "**Standard 3**" with 3 tests and have it run properly? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you need to do :

1. Upgrade to the latest released version of TestNG.
2. Build an implementation of [org.testng.IAlterSuiteListener](https://jitpack.io/com/github/cbeust/testng/master-6.11-g1d80d76-102/javadoc/org/testng/IAlterSuiteListener.html)
3. Move your implementation that you created in ISuiteListener into this listener implementation.
4. Wire in this listener via the `<listeners>` tag in your suite XML File (or) via `ServiceLoaders` (As described in the javadocs of this interface)

Comment: Thank you! It's interesting that the `IAlterSuiteListener` can't be added by the `@Listener` annotation. Maybe that's why it doesn't appear on the TestNG documentation page